# Matlab Components needed for Electrical Engineering Students

Tags: matlab

I am installing Matlab, and now I need to select the components that are required for electrical engineering projects, circuits, ect. ( for undergraduate students, not professionals)
the list is attached, please let me know which ones to select, I don't want to select them all because I know I don't need them all and also they will slow down my laptop's speed for sure.
[image]

Comment: It is always better to select "typical" or "complete" installation when you don't know to *customize*.

Comment: I don't believe that's an option for matlab, @nidhin.  It's all the libraries or none unless you go custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very difficult - if not impossible to answer without knowing what you will do with MATLAB. I am aware that you possibly don't know this yourself yet. So, I'm trying to give a generic answer.

These are the packages I would suggest for any installation, as they are useful for many fields:

- Simulink: is very useful for process modelling and simulation. (basic installation, not all toolboxes)
- Optimization Toolbox: You will need optimization in most fields.
- Statistics Toolbox: Same for statistics, it's always usefull
- Parallel Computing Toolbox: Nice to speed up long calculations. I grew to like `parfor` very much.
- Symbolic Math Toolbox: Unless you have a dedicated symbolic math software (e.g. Mathematica, Maple) i suggest you install the symbolic toolbox. It is not as powerful as the mentioned programs but a good alternative if you don't have these.
- Signal Processing Toolbox: Is a nice toolbox with many features which are not only useful in signal processing
- Curve Fitting Toolbox: Includes regression, splines etc.

Depending on what you will do, the following toolboxes might come in handy:

- Image Processing Toolbox: the name says it all.
- Image Acquisition Toolbox: to control cameras (USB, GigE, ...)
- Computer Vision Toolbox: is more for real-time image/video processing
- DSP System Toolbox and Fixed-Point Designer: if you are likely to design algorithms for DSPs
- Data Acquisition and Instrument Control Toolbox: if you will do measurements directly with MATLAB
- Communication Systems Toolbox: again, the name says it all.

This is just a try to estimate what can be useful, so don't be too hard on me if I forgot something or you see it differently. I am of course also open to suggestions.

Comment: are you saying I only need to select these components? I selected the mentioned ones and a few more ,I am installing them now.

Comment: That's the ones i think you will surely need. Selecting more is always good, one often finds useful functions in other toolboxes